# What does mean the phrase "fall through" in slang?

Tags: meaning-in-context

It's from GTA 5, just look [at 12:07](https://youtu.be/hEKdENf5kGk?t=727) on Youtube.

As two characters leave a car dealership, one homie is offering to another to get in a car, he says:

> How 'bout we fall through, homie?

What does it mean at this context?

Comment: Without more context, it's not possible to say that it might have nothing to do with getting into the car.

Comment: What is the source of this quote? A film? A book? Personal experience? please cite your sources.

Comment: @Weather Vane, there is no context, just routine phrase

Comment: Also - looking at the in-game subtitles the phrase is actually '*How 'bout **we** fall through, homie?*' Still not entirely sure what it means though, although if I had to guess, maybe it means to go home (as they then drive home)